# How to create association between users and lobbies using sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have following models:

```
// User model
    const User = sequelize.define('users_dev', {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.UUID
            primaryKey: true
        },
        fullName: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        }
    )}

// Game lobby model
    const Lobby = sequelize.define('lobbies_dev', {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.UUID,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        player1: {
            type: Sequelize.UUID // Need reference by user id
        },
        player2: {
            type: Sequelize.UUID // Need reference by user id
        }

    )}
```

How can I create an association between the lobby.player1 (and 2) and the user.id? So when I will make request to the lobby later, I could get information about my user?

I read the documentation, tried many options, but only got errors for 6 hours of work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To properly associate, you don't define User fields in the Lobby model, you instead have to associate them:

```
// User model
    const User = sequelize.define('user', { // note: changed the name
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.UUID
            primaryKey: true
        },
        fullName: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        }
    )}

// Game lobby model
    const Lobby = sequelize.define('lobby', { // note: changed the name
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.UUID,
            primaryKey: true
        }
    })

// associate Users and Lobby
User.belongsTo(Lobby) // this will add 'lobbyId' attribute to User
```

You can then `create` or `update` instance models with this association

Example:

```
const lobby = await Lobby.create({})
const player1 = await User.create({ fullName: 'a name', lobbyId: lobby.id})
```

This will allow you to join later:

```
const lobby = await Lobby.findById(id, { include: [{ model: User }] })
```

I would also strongly advise changing `users_dev` and `lobbies_dev` to `user` and `lobby` respectively in `define`, as Sequelize uses these strings to name the models.

Comment: Thank you, Is it avaliable to associate my `User.id` with `Lobby.player1` field?

Comment: I would suggest not having a player1 or player2 field, they don't seem necessary. If you would like to do that though, the docs have a section describing exactly that: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#enforcing-a-foreign-key-reference-without-constraints